# break out of if and foreach

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, break

I have a foreach loop and an if statement. If a match is found i need to ultimately break out of the foreach.

```
foreach ($equipxml as $equip) {

    $current_device = $equip->xpath("name");
    if ($current_device[0] == $device) {

        // Found a match in the file.
        $nodeid = $equip->id;

        <break out of if and foreach here>
    }
}
```

Comment: for php not js. i can't assume they behave the same.

Comment: gee - i've got to stop using jQuery so much. why did this get a downvote? +1, perfectly reasonable and well posed question.

Comment: i only asked the question because (for whatever reason) i couldn't wrap my head around the php break doc and their examples. all good though. i'm not here to get badges and points, just fine answers.

Answer (score 761, accepted):

`if` is not a loop structure, so you cannot "break out of it".

You can, however, break out of the `foreach` by simply calling [`break`](http://www.php.net/break). In your example it has the desired effect:

```
$device = "wanted";
foreach($equipxml as $equip) {
    $current_device = $equip->xpath("name");
    if ( $current_device[0] == $device ) {
        // found a match in the file            
        $nodeid = $equip->id;

        // will leave the foreach loop immediately and also the if statement
        break;
        some_function(); // never reached!
    }
    another_function();  // not executed after match/break
}
```

---

Just for completeness for others who stumble upon this question looking for an answer..

[`break`](http://www.php.net/break) takes an optional argument, which defines *how many* loop structures it should break. Example:

```
foreach (['1','2','3'] as $a) {
    echo "$a ";
    foreach (['3','2','1'] as $b) {
        echo "$b ";
        if ($a == $b) { 
            break 2;  // this will break both foreach loops
        }
    }
    echo ". ";  // never reached!
}
echo "!";
```

Resulting output:

> 1 3 2 1 !

Comment: Useful, thank you. Extra karma for mentioning the argument. The if-loop thing seems like a hack, though. Why not just wrap the rest of the statements in another if? I know you were just trying to be helpful, but note to the newbies.

Comment: For those of you landing here but searching how to break out of a loop that contains an include statement use return instead of continue.

Comment: What if its a switch statement? Switch statements also use breaks. Would somebody simply put two breaks inside the switch e.g { case "break": echo 'break the switch and the loop'; break;break; }   ?

Comment: @Jevon no you would also simply write `switch($a) { case 'x': switch($b) { case 'x': break 2; }; break; }`  the inner `break 2` leaves both switch statements.

Answer (score 17):

```
foreach($equipxml as $equip) {
    $current_device = $equip->xpath("name");
    if ( $current_device[0] == $device ) {
        // found a match in the file            
        $nodeid = $equip->id;
        break;
    }
}
```

Simply use [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php). That will do it.

Comment: so then the break is breaking from the foreach and not the if. i think my confusion was from this statement `if ($abort_if_block) break;`
i had originally set `break 2` and it failed. thanks

Comment: Watch out for the break construct. If you forget the ; after it, it might get the result of next expression and start behaving unexpectedly (IE jumping out of much more than you would have wanted). I know everyone suggests against the use of GOTO, but I think that, for all those cases when you can't really do better than using a break, a goto can be a better option. Of course, for forward jumping (not too far either) only and without abuse! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A safer way to approach breaking a `foreach` or `while` loop in PHP is to nest an incrementing counter variable and `if` conditional inside of the original loop. This gives you tighter control than `break;` which can cause havoc elsewhere on a complicated page.

Example:

```
// Setup a counter
$ImageCounter = 0;

// Increment through repeater fields
while ( condition ):
  $ImageCounter++;

   // Only print the first while instance
   if ($ImageCounter == 1) {
    echo 'It worked just once';
   }

// Close while statement
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2):

For those of you landing here but searching how to break out of a loop that contains an include statement use return instead of break or continue.

```
<?php

for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        include(do_this_for_even.php);
    }
    else {
        include(do_this_for_odd.php);
    }
}

?>
```

If you want to break when being inside do_this_for_even.php you need to use return. Using break or continue will return this error: Cannot break/continue 1 level. I found more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988281/why-does-cannot-break-continue-1-level-comes-in-php)