# stop preventing HTML code rendering with Return and Die function in php

Tags: php

As you know in a php script when you call Return or Die it prevents the rest of HTML codes from rendering.

In an occasion when I just want to stop the php script but not whole the page what would I do?

Ex:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['txt_username']))
{
    echo "Please enter your username";
    return;
}
?>
<i want="this html">to be rendered</i>
```

I want my HTML codes to be rendered afterward.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: `return !== die` and furthermore what's wrong with the code above?

Comment: Don't include the file or use `file_get_contents` instead of `require`/`include`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215588/break-out-of-if-and-foreach

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but you need to stop the PHP code to execute, but the HTML to render? You might need output buffer or functions.

E.g.:

```
<form action="" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="txt_username" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
function doSmth(&$password) {
    if(!isset($_POST['txt_username']))
    {
        echo "Please enter your username";
        return false;
    }
    $password .= "333";
    echo "You password has been changed to $password";
}

$password = 128;
doSmth($password);
?>
<body>
    <p> <b> Your password is <?= $password; ?> </b></p>
</body>
```

Examples:

- Text field is set:
- Output:

  You password has been changed to 128333

  Your password is 128333

---

- Text field is not set:
- Output:

  Please enter your username

  Your password is 128

Comment: When php interpreter reaches the 'return' or 'die' statement it stops everything. how to avoid that?

Comment: @AliRashidi when the PHP interpreter reaches `return` in a function call, it will stop everything in the scope of the function, but not the global/outer scope. My example will render HTML even `$_POST['txt_username']` is not set

Comment: In the mentioned code above when 'txt_username' in undefined you will end up with a blank page. try it

Comment: @AliRashidi see my new example

Comment: @AliRashidi the `<p> Your password...</p>` will always render, but the logic inside the function will not be done, if the `txt_username` is not set and the proper error message will be displayed E.g.: the password will not change from `128` to `128333` because there is a return

Answer (score 0):

Use the conditional statement to include more PHP is needed. The HTML can then be rendered regardless of the PHP's if/else statement. Example:

```
<?php
if( !isset($_POST['txt_username']) )
{
 echo "Please enter your username";
}
else
{
    //Some dditional PHP functions
}
?>
<i want="this html">to be rendered</i>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$stateOfRender = false;
if(!(isset($_SESSION['sessionid']))) {
    echo "You have not logged yet. Now you are redirecting to Login Page";
    header('Refresh: 5; URL = login.php');
} else {
    $stateOfRender = true;
}

// In everywhere you can use this variable to control your statement
// for example:
if($stateOfRender) {
    // Open DB connection and fetch user data and settle it to page.
}
?>
```

In my php code i use this method to handle process. Generally i use it in db connection. If dbconnection is success i render page with control this variable. I hope to it helps you.